# convert unix timestmp to date

Tags: php, php-5.3, php-5.2

how to I convert a unix timestamp 1280214000 to human readable date?

Comment: *(reference)* [DateTime functions in PHP](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`strftime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php).  E.g.:

```
strftime("%x", 1280214000);
```

See the documentation for all the formatting options.

Answer (score 6):

you can also use the date function

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
<?php
// Assuming today is March 10th, 2001, 5:16:18 pm, and that we are in the
// Mountain Standard Time (MST) Time Zone

$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");                 // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm
$today = date("m.d.y");                         // 03.10.01
$today = date("j, n, Y");                       // 10, 3, 2001
$today = date("Ymd");                           // 20010310
$today = date('h-i-s, j-m-y, it is w Day');     // 05-16-18, 10-03-01, 1631 1618 6 Satpm01
$today = date('\i\t \i\s \t\h\e jS \d\a\y.');   // it is the 10th day.
$today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");               // Sat Mar 10 17:16:18 MST 2001
$today = date('H:m:s \m \i\s\ \m\o\n\t\h');     // 17:03:18 m is month
$today = date("H:i:s");                         // 17:16:18
?>
```

Just pass in your unix timestamp as the second parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [date](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//Monday 8th of August 2005 03:12:46 PM
echo(date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A", "1280214000"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `date` function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php